# Load data from sqlite database to GAE datastore from AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to upload a sqllite database to GAE, open it in read mode and than copy data from a database table to a datastore model.

Thank's in advance,
Roberto

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take an alternative approach, where you *locally* use the [bulk loader tool](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) to upload your data to the GAE data store.

Comment: Thank you Josvic, but the problem is that the sqlite db is set by e-mail from a device. My app would get the db directly from Google Apps email and process it without exit from the Google infrastructure.

Comment: @user856313 Unsure how you can do that. It surely doesn't follow a "standard" way of doing things. I.e. replacing live data from an email, can be quite risky IMO.